# Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'member' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

Unable to convert discord.Member to a acceptable mysql type:

```
  @app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 3.0, key=lambda i: (i.guild_id, i.user.id))
  @app_commands.command(name = "warn", description = "hi")
  async def warn(self, 
  interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.Member, reason: str, amount: str) -> None:
        server = discord.Interaction.guild_id
        sql = "INSERT INTO warnings (warns, ID, Reason, guild) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = (amount, user, reason, server)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Added Data")
```

discord.Member should be inserting into 'ID'

[image: ID Type]

[[image: The Error2]

Comment: I think you want to store something like `user.name`

Answer (score 0):

Your column is named `ID` which suggests you want to store an ID in there, but the value you're passing is a `discord.Member` instance. You can't insert that into a database. MYSQL has no idea how to take a `discord.Member` object and store it in a db.

If you want to store the ID, access the attribute using `user.id` and store *that*.

Comment: user.id isn't found using discord.Interaction.User.id

Comment: What exactly did you try? Literally ``discord.Interaction.user`` or an _instance_ of it? Because that attribute exists on that class. What does your error message look like? Can you update your question to what you've got now?